# Is there a definitive list of FSEvents event flags?

Tags: fsevents

I've been searching but cannot find a definitive list.  I'm logging certain events and I'm not sure what they are - would be very useful to have a lookup table to be able to see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: Is there something missing with the documentation here (the list looks pretty definitive to me):  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html  (Just search for FSEventStreamEventFlags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I found the following in the FSEvents Reference under constants / FSEventStreamEventFlags

Please look this up so you can see the descriptions of each flag. I was a little confused at first, but then I realized that you only ever get some of these events, depending on how you set up the stream. If you set it up to NOT get file events then you only get the first half of the events. If you set it up TO get file events then you only get the second half (so far as I can tell and have noticed).

- kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagMount
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagUnmount

---

- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemInodeMetaMod
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsFile
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir
- kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink